# How to check if snmp v3 is available with snmp4j

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have to check if snmp v3 is available on the device being managed via snmp4j. If not, I have to use snmp v2c. But how do I check the availability via snmp4j? Is there a finished method or standard way of doing it?

I thought of something like:

```
private Target getTarget()
{
    Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(ip);
    CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
    target.setCommunity(new OctetString(community));
    target.setAddress(targetAddress);
    target.setRetries(2);
    target.setTimeout(1000);

    //Check here (with if)
    if(snmpv3_is_available)
         target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
    else
         target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);

    return target;
}
```

Hopefully someone knows an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each known IP address, you can send the SNMP v3 discovery message (it supports GET/GET-BULK and so on),

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SNMP%20Device%20Discovery&referringTitle=Documentation

SNMP v3 enabled entities must respond to that according to the standard.

So for snmp4j, you should see if there is just a method to do so.